# gcc: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input

Tags: gcc

The compiler throws the following error: "gcc: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input".
What does this mean? How to remove it?
Thanks for the answer!

I tried to compile the program in Terminal: gcc - ex_1.c ex c

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this command:

```
gcc ex_1.c -o ex_c
```

(it will compile and make executable in the same time)

In this command:

- gcc is the compiler.
- ex_1.c is the source code file you want to compile.
- -o ex_c specifies that the compiled output should be named ex_c.

After that you can execute the executable:

```
./ex_c
```

The error message "gcc: error: -E or -x required" means that you are attempting to use the gcc compiler without specifying the language of the input source code using the -x option. The -E option is also mentioned in the error message; it's used to run the preprocessor only.

You can use another command, but it's not necessary, it's just show the language (which is C):

```
gcc -x c ex_1.c -o ex_c
./ex_c
```

But the ordinary way to compile and execute is:

```
gcc -c ex1.c    //1
gcc -o ex_c ex1.o    //2
./ex_c    //3
```

- "ex1.c" : This is the name of the source code file you want to compile.
  The command `1` compiles ex1.c into an object file named ex1.o. This object file contains the compiled machine code representation of your C code but isn't yet a complete executable. This step separates compilation and linking.
- "ex1.o" : This is the object file that was generated in the previous step.
  The command `2` takes the object file ex1.o and links it with the necessary libraries and runtime components to create a complete executable named ex_c. The executable is ready to be run.
- "./ex_c" : The command `3` runs the compiled executable named ex_c.